# With the help of ODBC connection, get foreign keys from an oracle db

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc, key

I want to collect all the Design Information from an Database. It was possible for me to gather the most information, but I cant get Information about Foreign Keys! Is there an possibility to get the Foreign keys from an Oracle DB with an ODBC Connection?!?!?

for example MSSql gives the possibility in C# with:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_fkeys", myConnection);
```

Is there existing an alternative for ODBC in C#?

Comment: Oracle has data dictionary views for all table meta-data.  Go google that.

Answer (score 1):

ODBC has functions that allow database-independent querying of metadata.  Start with [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms712628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the ODBC Programmer's Reference and look at the section labeled "Obtaining information about the data source's system tables (catalog functions)".  In particular, you're probably interested in the [SQLForeignKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Share and enjoy.